# Can't connect any virtual device to android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am trying to set up my android studio to connect or read the virtual device i fail every time !

i tried to download (intel X86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) ) but the download every time does not completed successfully with a message ( please file a bug to intel  )!!!!

when i'm trying to run the app from the cmd it gives me a message that (No supported devices connected.)

when even the virtual machine is running and i click run to RUN my App it gives me that error :

```
'Dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you open the virtual device and opened **flutter console** and entered "flutter run" oh android studio also works
2. I had a similar error: "Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"

Try flutter doctor in the flutter console and run flutter pub get on your project

Note: I'm not the best at this stuff

Edit:

Using a physical device is probably better...

Virtual devices are extremely laggy for me (windows 10) and it's just hard in general.

Edit 2: (important)

3. Did you install the flutter plugin?
4. Did you do:

File>New>New flutter project>Select flutter application?

This is what solved it for me

Comment: it worked perfectly (File>New>New flutter project>Select flutter application)

Comment: @Minawagdy you might want to mark this as the answer to help other people who have the same problem